# Delay in iframe load

Tags: javascript, iframe-resizer

Here is the how the iframeresizer log looks like:

> [iFrameSizer][Host page: glu] IFrame scrolling disabled for glu
>   iframeResizer.min.js:8[iFrameSizer][Host page: glu] [init] Sending msg to iframe[glu] (glu:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:lowestElement:null:null:0:true:parent:scroll) targetOrigin: *
>
> iframeResizer.min.js:8 [iFrameSizer][Host page: glu] [iFrame.onload] Sending msg to iframe[glu] (glu:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:lowestElement:null:null:0:true:parent:scroll) targetOrigin: *
>
> iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9 [iFrameSizer][glu] Initialising iFrame (https://www.kultureshop.in/blog/about-ks/)

You'll notice that the host page sent 2 messages to the hosted/iframe page. The first one was ignored. The iframe page reacted to the second message.

The problem is that there is a big time gap between the first and second message.

Does anyone know how long does the host page script wait before it resends the message to the iframe page? Can this be reduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sends the first message when it first runs and the second one once the onload event of the iFrame loads. If your using the latest version, the iFrame will also send a message to the parent page once it is ready to receive the message.